# SharePoint WebPart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a solution with 2 projects

**SharePoint.Project**

- WebPart

  - Elements.xml
  - WebPart.webpart

**Web.Project**

- WebParts

  - WebPart.cs (NameSpace = Web.Project.WebParts)

SharePoint.Project includes a reference to Web.Project. The SharePoint.Project packages the output from Web.Project and deploys it to the GAC. After the solution is deployed both SharePoint.Project.DLL and Web.Project.DLL exist in the GAC and the web.config of my sharepoint site include a SafeControl that identifies the **FullName** of the assembly "Web.Project.DLL", the **Namespace** "Web.Project.WebParts", and the **Type** "*".

**The Problem**
Attempt to add the webpart to a page in sharepoint site gives me the error below

```
A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported.
The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be another solution to this problem but what I ended up doing was create a `WebPart.cs` file in **SharePoint.Project** and having it derive from the `WebPart.cs` from **Web.Project**, and changing the `Elements.xml` and `WebPart.webpart` files to reference the `WebPart.cs` in **SharePoint.Project**

Answer (score 1):

You should check version number and publickeytoken of safe control dll. These property must be similar to  dll deployed in GAC.

Comment: +1 because this is helpful troubleshooting information, but even after I verified the "SafeControl" entry that was added to the web.config was exactly correct for my assembly, namespace and type, I was still getting the error